# Flutter + auto_route. No route generated for a flutter package project

Tags: flutter

I created a Flutter-Package-Project and tried to generate the project route using auto_route, but unfortunately no route will be generated, but also no errors, just:

> [INFO] Succeeded after 83ms with 0 outputs (0 actions)

My AutoRoute definition looks like:

```dart
    @MaterialAutoRouter(
      replaceInRouteName: 'Page,Route',
      routes: <AutoRoute>[
        AutoRoute(page: ItemsListPage, initial: true),
        AutoRoute(path: ':itemId', page: ItemDetailPage, fullMatch: true),
      ],
    )
    class $ItemsRouter {}
```

I specified all dependencies in the pubspec.yaml:

```yaml
    dependencies:
      ...
      auto_route: ^2.2.0
      ...
    
    dev_dependencies:
      ...
      auto_route_generator: ^2.1.0
      build_runner: ^2.0.6
      ...
```

And I run flutter packages pub run build_runner build from the package project.

Maybe someone has an idea, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you try to add an empty path to `ItemsListPage`? 
AutoRoute(path: '', page: ItemsListPage, initial: true),

Comment: @Tima Are you able to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug in this row:

```
AutoRoute(path: ':itemId', page: ItemDetailPage, fullMatch: true),
                 ^^^^^^^
```

I think it must be:

```
AutoRoute(path: '/:itemId', page: ItemDetailPage, fullMatch: true),
```